# cp doesn't copy special characters

Tags: bash, debian, special-characters, cp

I'm running a Java program on Debian machines. Among others, this piece of software copies some directories: `cp -r --remove-destination /etc/some/dir /opt/some/dir`. However, when other people are running this program, some special characters (e.g., é) are not copied properly (i.e. ?). I think it comes from the user locals. But I don't want to modify it.

Does somebody know how to copy with `cp` or another command some files with special characters without tampering the user locals? Or have I to tackle this problem with Java file copying API?

Thanks!

Comment: Please be precise: Are you refering to the filenames or the content of the files, in which case you likely mean "text files"? The content should be copied bytewise. If source- and target system have different endianess, and you have UTF without BOM, this could be a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a solution in specifying the encoding to use to Java:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 file.jar
```

If you do not specify it, the JVM will take the encoding from the environment variables of the user executing the `.jar`.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file system is mounted on Your `/etc/some/dir`?

Try to mount with option `iocharset=utf8`

Comment: The type is `ext4`. I tried to add the option `iocharset=utf8` to `/etc/fstab` and then `mount -a` but the issue persists.